# Why is the css for my table not working?

Tags: css

I am a student learning how to program. I cant figure out why nothing is working in my table CSS. I am trying to shrink my cells so all of it fits on the screen without having to side scroll. here is my html code. I am also using Aptana Studio 3 as an editor if that matters any.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="MainCSS.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="IndexTableCSS.css">
        <title>Noah's Ark Pet Sanctuary</title>
</head>
<body>
<header id="header">
    <img src="SanctuaryHeader.jpg">
</header>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="santuary.html">ANIMAL SANCTUARY</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="hospital.html">ANIMAL HOSPITAL</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="adoptDOG.html">ADOPTION CENTER</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="petHelth.html">PET HEALTH CARE</a></li>
            <li><a href="petTraining.html">TRAINING TIPS</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="donations.html">DONATIONS</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="volteering.html">VOLUNTEERING</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="store.html">OUR STORE</a></li>
        <li><a href="newsEvents.html">NEWS &amp; EVENTS</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<br>
<br>
<table id="SanctuaryTable">
        <tr>
        <td><img src="mural.jpg"></td>
        <td><img src="santary.jpg"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Noah's Ark Pet Sanctuary was founded and incorporated as an Illinois Non-Profit corporation in 1978
             by a small group of residents who care about animals.  One of our goals is to educate the public on 
             the proper care and population control of domestic dogs and cats<br>
            <br>
            <strong>What we do</strong>
            <br>
            Noah's Ark takes in adoptable cats and dogs from Rockford and the surrounding area.  
            Once at the sanctuary they receive proper medical care and are put up for adoption into qualified homes for a nominal fee
            <br>
            <br>
            <img src="dogSit.jpg">
        </td>
        <td>            
            Noah's Ark Animal Sanctuary 
            <br>
            111 North First Street
            <br>
            Rockford IL 61107
            <br>
            <br>
            <strong>Hours</strong>
            <br>
            Mon - Tue - Thurs - Fri  9:30 am - 5:00 pm
            <br>
            <br>
            Wed 9:30 am 3:30 pm
            <br>
            <br>
            Sat 9:30 am - 3:00 pm
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <img src="CatPlay.jpg"> 
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><img src="ArkFooter.jpg"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body> 
</html>
```

here is my IndexTableCSS :

```
#SanctuaryTable
{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    word-wrap:break-word ;
    width: 500px;
}

.small
{
    width: 50%; 
}
```

I looked at my MainCSS file and did not see anything that should be interfering with the other CSS but here is that code as well:

```
body
{
font-family: Arial,  Verdana, sans-serif;
margin-left: 40px;
}

ul 
{
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

ul li 
{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

li ul 
{
    display: none;
}

ul li a 
{
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
    background: #1e7c9a;
    margin-left: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
ul li a:hover 
{
background: #3b3b3b;
}

li:hover ul 
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

li:hover li 
{
    float: none;
    font-size: 11px;
}

li:hover a 
{ 
    background: #3b3b3b;
}

li:hover li a:hover
{
    background: #1e7c9a;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that the images are wider than 500px?

Comment: I see that you have link rel="stylesheet" href="MainCSS.css">; Can you confirm if the css file is in the same folder? If not it will need an absolutive Path like, href="C:\\SomeFolder\\MainCSS.css"

Comment: have you tried:   table {width:100%;table-layout:fixed;}  .... if that works i advise you to keep looking after CSS tutorial and how to use,  build and style tables.

Comment: If your goal is to make the table fit in the window without having a horizontal scroll bar, [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/6xG6p/) shows you've succeeded. Are you sure the stylesheets get loaded?

Comment: Oh, you're abusing not only `<table>`, but also `<img>`, `<strong>` and `<br>` elements. But we'll get to that later. Let's solve the problems first.

Comment: I don't seem to understand the issue. Checkout [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/99Hx7/4/). It's your code _presentified_. Identify the problem, please.

Comment: i appreciate any comments on how to code better. yes all the files are in the same folder that was a typo on my part calling MainCSS a folder.

Comment: the problem i was having was when i opened the home page index.html the cells to the table were too big. i am trying to have the table fit on the screen without a horizontal scroll bar. no matter what number i tryed the cells would not increase or decrease in size. so i added a simple border to my css and that did not show so for some reason my css is not working for my table and i dont know why.

Comment: the MainCSS file is working. i dont understand why my code is working in the the fiddle that mr lister and yasky has produced but doesent work in aptana studio. so i know its not the code itself so thank you all for showing me that and and suggestions on how do to it better would be appreciated.

Comment: if you leave any suggestions please do not leave code. more like ideas and topics to research (google is my friend). ty

Comment: OK. 1) Check if the encoding of the CSS files is the same as the encoding of the HTML files. 2) Check if the filetype of the CSS files is OK. For instance in Firefox, load the CSS file into a window, then View Page Info. The type should be `text/css`. 3) Speaking about Firefox, it is notorious for caching CSS; that is, even if you change your CSS file, it will still use the older version it once loaded. Until you clear its cache. So have you done that? 4) Which browser have you tried? Do they all behave identically?

Comment: i have tryed both firefox and chrome no change in either. i did copy the code into different notepad ++ files and it worked then. so im thinking its something to do with the web editor software i am using.

Comment: Mr Lister maby you can explain to my why this is happening. I ended up going through and deleting the images out of the table and now i can increase and decrease the cell size. the images are what was causing the problem with increasing and decreasing the cells in the web editor why is that ? sorry if this is a noob question i only had one semester of html so it was learn everything i can as quick as i can.

Comment: also im interested in your comment earlyer :  
"Oh, you're abusing not only <table>, but also <img>, <strong> and <br> elements. But we'll get to that later. Let's solve the problems first"   im wondering how you can abuse those?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not familiar with Aptana Studio 3, but I know that things can go seriously wrong in Visual Studio:
By default it saves its files with the Windows-1252 encoding, until you have characters in your files that can't be represented in Windows-1252, then it will save them in Unicode, by which it means UTF-16.
Now by itself this won't be a disaster, but many browsers expect their stylesheets and script files to have the same encoding as their HTML files, so if you have saved one file as Windows-1252 and the other as UTF-16, they have become incompatible.

If Aptana has similar issues, the only solution I know of is to load all your files, then save all of them with the same encoding, preferably UTF-8, and then the problem won't happen any more.

---

Another point is that you may not realise the normal behaviour of a table is to treat all its widths as *minimum* values. Take [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/HnB3G/3/) for instance, it sets both the table and the td to 300px, but the content is much wider, so the table expands to the full width of the content. This is in contrast to most other HTML elements (like the `<p>` in the fiddle) that do respect the width, but let the content overflow out of their boundaries.

---

Then the abuse thing. Well, it's just that you shouldn't use HTML elements for things they are not designed for.
For instance, `<strong>` is meant to bring attention to something, or in a piece of prose, as strong emphasis (the equivalent of raising your voice), those kind of things. Not simply to make a piece of text bold. To do that, use CSS. Or if you read the HTML5 spec carefully, you can even use `<b>`. Because `<b>` doesn't have an intrinsic meaning, it *can* be used simply to make something bold (I wouldn't recommend it though).
Ditto for the other things I mentioned. I put together a HTML abuse guide on my own site [here](http://www.strictquirks.nl/standards/htmlabuseguide.html), if you'll pardon the plug.

Comment: thank you for the advice. its been helpful. i went to the site and i understand i always thought tables were a good way to layout a page. i am thinking im gona take that code turn it into divs instead it sounds like thats the more professional way of doing things.

Answer (score 1):

This sentence raised alarm bells for me:

> I looked at my MainCSS folder and did not see anything that should be
>   interfering with the other CSS but here is that code as well:

You haven't defined a directory in your href to the css?? It should read something like:

```
<link rel="styleheet" type="text/css" href="directory/stylesheet-name.css />
```

Be careful with your naming conventions and make sure you are consistent with captilisation, camel-case or all lowercase.

Comment: I thought "MainCSS folder" was a typo for "MainCSS file". But you have a point about the casing.

Comment: Could be. You're probably right. Might be worth the OP refining his question a bit, because at the moment there is very little to go on... I hate questions like this. They don't like helping us help them, do they?

Comment: My question was why are my cells to my table not changing their width no matter what number i put the width at in my css. does that make it clearer on the issue i am having ?

Comment: also all of these files are in the same folder so me calling the MainCSS file a folder was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a div wrapper to put all of your paragraphs into that constrains the width.  The width of the wrapper would then be written into the CSS a good width is usually around 960px.

```
<div id="wrapper">
all of your code here
</div>

as for your CSS

#div wrapper {
width:960px;
}
```